# python asyncio add_done_callback with async def

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have 2 functions: The first one, `def_a`, is an asynchronous function and the second one is `def_b` which is a regular function and called with the result of `def_a` as a callback with the `add_done_callback` function.

My code looks like this:

```
import asyncio

def def_b(result):
    next_number = result.result()
    # some work on the next_number
    print(next_number + 1)

async def def_a(number):
    await some_async_work(number)
    return number + 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = asyncio.ensure_future(def_a(1))
task.add_done_callback(def_b)
response = loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
```

And it's work perfectly.

The problem began when also the second function, `def_b`, became asynchronous. Now it looks like this:

```
async def def_b(result):
    next_number = result.result()
    # some asynchronous work on the next_number
    print(next_number + 1)
```

But now I can not provide it to the `add_done_callback` function, because it's not a regular function.

My question is- Is it possible and how can I provide `def_b` to the `add_done_callback` function if `def_b` is asynchronous?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`add_done_callback` is considered a "low level" interface.  When working with coroutines, you can [chain them](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#example-chain-coroutines) in many ways, for example:

```
import asyncio


async def my_callback(result):
    print("my_callback got:", result)
    return "My return value is ignored"


async def coro(number):
    await asyncio.sleep(number)
    return number + 1


async def add_success_callback(fut, callback):
    result = await fut
    await callback(result)
    return result


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro(1))
task = add_success_callback(task, my_callback)
response = loop.run_until_complete(task)
print("response:", response)
loop.close()
```

Keep in mind `add_done_callback` will still call the callback if your future raises an exception (but calling `result.result()` will raise it).

Comment: thank you for sharing, out of curiousity, what is the benefit of using ensure future over using await my_coro within my_callback

Comment: `ensure_future(coro)` just queues `coro()` for later execution and does not immediately start `coro()`.

Comment: asyncio.create_task() should be used used instead of asyncio.ensure_future() in Python 3.7+ https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

Comment: Why this is the right answer. I thought use `asyncio.ensure_future` in callback function is the right one.

Answer (score 5):

This only works for one future job, if you have multiple async jobs, they will blocks each other, a better way is using asyncio.as_completed() to iterate future list:

```
import asyncio

async def __after_done_callback(future_result):
    # await for something...
    pass

async def __future_job(number):
    await some_async_work(number)
    return number + 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(__future_job(x)) for x in range(100)]  # create 100 future jobs

for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
    result = await f
    await __after_done_callback(result)

loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the aiodag library. It's a very lightweight wrapper around asyncio that abstracts away some of the async plumbing that you usually have to think about. From this example you won't be able to tell that things are running asynchronously since it's just 1 task that depends on another, but it is all running async.

```
import asyncio
from aiodag import task

@task
async def def_b(result):
    # some asynchronous work on the next_number
    print(result + 1)

@task
async def def_a(number):
    await asyncio.sleep(number)
    return number + 1

async def main():
    a = def_a(1)
    b = def_b(a)  # this makes task b depend on task a
    return await b

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
response = loop.run_until_complete(main())
```